# how to write float value to csv in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have list of float numbers and I wanna write them in a csv file vertical (one number in one row) when I write for example 6,03333 to csv it shows like 6,0,3,3,3,3 what should I do ?
when I write it horizontal (all number in one row) its alright
my code is

```
babah = list()
with open('ja.csv', 'w', newline='') as uu:
    dw = csv.writer(uu)
    dw.writerows(babah)
```

Comment: In the code you provide we do not see how you fill the `babah` list. Could you please give a bit more details about the exact code you are executing?

Comment: You cannot use `,` as both decimal and CSV field delimiter. Use either `.` for decimals, or another CSV field delimiter, like e.g. `;`

Answer (score 0):

According to the doc https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows

`csv.writerows` seems to take elements of an iterable (like a list) and build a row, each single element is in a specific column.

Assuming your input list looks like `["6,03333", "6,03333"]`, your csv file will look like:

```
6,",",0,3,3,3,3
6,",",0,3,3,3,3
```

Because each element of the main list is a string and **strings are iterables.**

You can try to reshape input list with sub lists, each element for a column like:

`babah = [["row_1", "row_2"], ["6,03333", "6,03333"]]`

wich will give:

```
row_1,row_2
"6,03333","6,03333"
```